# Need to share a record with a Community User and all others in their account. Can this be done without code?

Tags: community, sharing

I have a Custom Object X that has Org Wide Defaults of "Private". The owners on the records are always internal users.

We would like to share the object with customers that belong to the account for which the record is related to.

**Example**:

ObjectX 1 is related to Account 1
ObjectX 2 is related to Account 2

User 1 belongs to Account 1.
User 2 belongs to Account 2.
User 3 belongs to Account 1.
All three users are customer community users.

**Wanted**:
User 1 and User 3 **should** be able to see all the Object X records for Account 1.
User 2 **should** be able to see all the Object X records for Account 2.

User 2 **should NOT** be able to see all the Object X records for Account 1.

**I have read that this is possible using Sharing Sets, but we do not have this feature in our org. I know we could accomplish this with Apex Sharing, but I would like to use that as a last resort.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sharing sets are accessible in Setup > Customize > Communities > Settings. Scroll down to the Sharing Sets section.

First, select the profile you want to apply it to. Then define the relationship by which a user derives access. In the screenshot below, Lease Contract is a custom object with a lookup to account. With this configuration, any Community user related to a particular Account will have access to the Lease Contracts that lookup to the same Account.

[image: Configuring a Sharing Set]

["Guide to Sharing Settings in Communities"](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000193532&language=en_US)

Comment: Hi Brian, we don't have that menu under Communities > Settings.

Comment: What type of communities licenses do you have?

Comment: I dont have any of the required ones. I would like to accomplish this without the Sharing Sets if possible. This article states the licenses I need and we don't have any of those. https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Why-can-t-I-create-a-Sharing-Set-for-my-Community&language=en_US